# Multiline string, invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add css to my page dynamically by building a css string that will be appended to the document's head. Since this string is long I want to break it up into multiple lines in my editor, so I do the following:

```
function generateCss(colors){
    var cssString = "* {margin: 0;padding: 0;} \ 
        #mainWrapper {width: 100vw;height: 100vh;background-color:#"+ colors['background'] + ";} \
        #mainWrapper div {height: 2vw;} \
        .cell {width: 2vw;background-color:#"+ colors['color1'] + ";display: inline-block;} \
        .active {background-color:#"+ colors['color2'] +" !important;}";
    console.log(cssString);
}
```

However, on the line where I create the `cssString` I get error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. Can anybody please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

This is a picture of my IDE for syntax highlighting reference:

[image: IDE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cssString = "* {margin: 0;padding: 0;} \
```

Note that you have an extra space at the end of the string. This causes the problem.

P.S. as a side note, it might be good to take in use something different then escaping, as stated in the following question:

[Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: I moved the slash closer to the actual text and am still getting the same error

Comment: NOT the leading space, you have a space after the "\" character: "s\s", gotta be "s\"

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
function generateCss(colors){
    var cssString = `* {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
        #mainWrapper {width: 100vw;height: 100vh;background-color:#${colors['background']};}
        #mainWrapper div {height: 2vw;}
        .cell {width: 2vw;background-color:#${colors['color1']};display: inline-block;}
        .active {background-color:#${colors['color2']}!important;}`;
    console.log(cssString);
}
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Explain what you changed and why. Don't forget to mention that it won't work with old browsers, since this is a very new Javascript feature.